# Remove margin from body in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm new to React and currently in the process of building a website, however I cannot get rid of the margin of the body.
My css in inside the index.js component and looks like this:

```html
<style jsx>{`
  body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
  }
`}</style>
```

Comment: I would suggest to add a css reset at the start of your app, https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ this will help you be more cross browser compatible and remove lots of unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use global with jsx style

```
<div>
    <style jsx global>{`
      body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
      }
    `}</style>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 8):

Where is your `root` defined? If it's within the body, you won't have access to the body element. Add it to your css or as an in-line style in your index.html.

**Inline index.html**

```
<body style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Comment: No need to add "px" to zero sizes. margin: 0 and padding: 0 works.

Answer (score 7):

You can simply create a `global.css`, (if it doesn't exist already) with css style:

```
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

and import this file in `_app.jsx`:

```
import "./global.css";
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer, but I just figured it out. The problem is that I'm using Next.js, which means I don't really have a body tag since it't provided by the "pages" feature from Next. The solution for me was to add the "global" attribute to the jsx which gives me the required access.
Just like this:

```
   <style jsx global>{`
         body{
             margin: 0px;
             padding: 0px;
         }
        `}</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting global styles in NEXT.js is like so:

- Create a top-level `styles` directory and a `global.css` file.
- Add the following CSS inside `styles/global.css`. This code resets some styles and changes the color of the a tag:

```
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, Segoe UI, Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu,
    Cantarell, Fira Sans, Droid Sans, Helvetica Neue, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.6;
  font-size: 18px;
}
...
```

- Finally, import the CSS file inside the pages/_app.js file you've created earlier on:

```
// `pages/_app.js`
import '../styles/global.css';
```

Answer adjusted from the [docs](https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/assets-metadata-css/global-styles).